# submitting form results into db - django

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

i created a form to save a post into db for my blog project. I've designed index page. now i am tryin to create a form to create new posts. before that i was using ' manage.py shell'

here is my view :

```
def addpost(request):
    form = addForm()
    if request.method=="POST":
        titleform = request.POST['title']
        bodyform = request.POST['body']
        checkform = request.POST['isdraft']
        if form.is_valid():
                n = Post(title = titleform, body = bodyform, isdraft=checkform)
                n.save()

                return HttpResponseRedirect('/admin/')
    else:
        pass
    return render(request,'userside/add.html',{'form':form,})
```

my model.py:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    body  = models.TextField()
    slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from='title',unique=True)
    posted = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    isdraft = models.BooleanField()
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

    @permalink
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return ('view_blog_post',None, {'postslug':self.slug})

class addForm(forms.Form):
    title = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    body  = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)
    isdraft = forms.BooleanField()
```

if i submit form as 'isdraft' field is False(unchecked) ; it gives error like:

**MultiValueDictKeyError at /admin/addpost/**

**"Key 'isdraft' not found in "**

and if i submit the form as 'isdraft' field is True(checked) ; it gives nothing. just refreshing form. no adding data into db.

i am doing sth wrong..

thank you

**edit :** Dmitry Beransky's answer worked for checkbox error. but it still doesnt add any data into db. just refreshes the form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The whole point of using a form is that it takes care of validation and cleaning, that is converting values to the proper data types. That's why you should be accessing `form.cleaned_data` rather than `reques.POST`, and you should be doing it inside the `if form.is_valid()` check.

**Edit**

I've just noticed that you're never passing request.POST to the form. So `form.is_valid()` will *never* be true.

Please go back and read the documentation about using a form in a view.

Comment: thank you it worked! but on request.POST , i can use 'isdraft',False for default value. now i HAVE TO check isdraft box on every submitting.

Comment: I'm sorry, I have no idea what you're asking. `form.cleaned_data['isdraft']` is a dict like any other, so you can use `.get('isdraft', False)`.

Answer (score 0):

If a checkbox is not checked in your HTML form, it's name/value is not going to be included in the data that the browser sends to your server.  Which meanst that the request.POST dictionary is not going to contain an entry for 'isdraft' which in turn will cause a key error when you try to read the isdraft value.  A solution is to change the way you read the value from the posted data to:

```
    checkform = request.POST.get('isdraft', False)
```

rather than throw an error if isdraft isn't found in the dictionary, this will set checkform to False (the default value in case of a missing key)

Comment: that fixed checkform error. thank you! but still it doesnt add any data to db. it should redirect admin page after submit data. but it still just refreshes the form.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your form does not validate at all. Have you checked if your code even reaches those lines after the if `form.is_valid()` statement ? If they do, what you've done there is right and should create the db row for your new entry, though you could have used
`Post.objects.create(....)` , and that would have taken away the need for calling the method `save()`.

Some points though:

- instead of checking for `request.POST` , check for `request.method == 'POST'` , cause there might be a post which has an empty POST dict ( in case no arguments have been submitted ), in that case `request.POST` fails to provide the right check .
  see the docs for more info : [request.POST](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.POST)
- instead of using `request.POST['var_name']` , use `request.POST.get('var_name', 'default_value')` , cause doing this like `request.POST['var_name']` might result in some exceptions ( in case for example the argument is not provided , like what happened for your checkform variable )
- Try accessing those variables through form.cleaned_data

and finally , you don't need the else statement in the end , just use the indentation :)

Comment: when i dont use else statement in the end ; all fields have ' this field is required' message when enter to page first time. if i use else : form=addForm() it is ok :)

Comment: you are validating the code after getting them , so before 'this field is required' is even able to do its job, you're code has ran into an exception if one is not presented. and well , seems you're not even passing request.POST to your form, so nothing whatsoever happens there and the form is never validated at all!